# dumping assets via assetic in prod using sass filter

Tags: symfony, sass, production-environment, assetic

Im trying to dump the assets (assetic:dump  --env=prod --no-debug) for my Symfony 2.5 app for the production env. 
I use the sass filter for including the .scss files:
    `{% stylesheets filter="sass"  ...`

I get the following error: 
`An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template ("There is no "sass" filter.")`

Is it required that you have all the filters (in this case `sass`) set up in your production environment? because I remember reading somewhere that in the prod environment symfony automatically does not use assetic.

I also tried dumping the assets locally (for prod) and then uploading them to the production server including the cache files (since my guess was symfony somehow must know which assets to look for, where) without any success.

Any thoughts on this are highly appreciated.

Comment: Well does your production environment have the sass filter?

Comment: No it does not.. There is no ruby installed

Comment: Im not positive on this but i believe that you still have to define the filter in the production config, even if you are not going to be using it. As long as you have the definition it should continue as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run the `assetic:dump --env=prod` command on your development environment, which will compile / dump the files as static css / js /etc. Those should then copied to the production server as part of the deployment process. On production, the Assetic Twig helper just resolves the assets to the proper filename, the compiled / static asset is served by your webserver as usual.